# Expire Page after page submit in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, submit

Is there a way to expire a form after the user presses submit and redirected to another external url.
I want to restrain the user from clicking the browser's back button and resubmit the form.

I have tried to set NoCache and NoStore in the Controller but the browser still held in cache (Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with MVC, the cache, or your browser; this is how HTTP headers handle `POST` requests.

Normally, when submitting a form to an internal or external URL you can avoid `POST` data being resubmitted by issuing a 302 "Moved Temporarily" redirect *after* you've processed the data, or by sending the request with AJAX or [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).

There are multiple examples with answers on Stack Overflow, simply search for "prevent form resubmission"